# Why does Alacarte give me this error when I try to add items to the menu?

Tags: menu, alacarte

When I try to add anything to the menu in 12.04, I get this error.

```
$ alacarte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/alacarte/Alacarte/MainWindow.py", line 317, in on_new_item_button_clicked
    process = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-desktop-item-edit', file_path], env=os.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in Alacarte.

You need to install the package `gnome-panel` as Alacarte wants to use a program (`gnome-desktop-item-edit`) that is in that package.

Comment: Has this bug been reported yet? If so, can I have a link?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alacarte/+bug/656735

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alacarte/+bug/1089438/

I have created a patch which is independent of gnome-panel installation. 
Thanks :)